# Swift: UIAlertController select subset from list

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a button that causes a `UIAlertController` to appear. I want to show a couple choices to the user and allow them to select a subset of the options.

```
[A  +]
[B   ]
[C  +]
[D   ]
[----]
[DONE]
```

I need to give an array to fill the options and then let the users select their subset (+ symbols in this example -> likely more common to use check marks). When they click `done` then it would let the code know their selection. Here is my current code from the button segue.

```
    @IBAction func insideButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Refresh", message: "All data will be lost.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Handle Ok logic here")
    }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
    }))

    presentViewController(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ChrisSlowik How I would do it

Comment: You're gonna have to make your own if you want to add functionality.

Comment: I don't think `UIAlertView` is well suited for this. I'd go with a `UITableView` that you can present in a popup or similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

From the UIAlertController docs: "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

You'll have to make your own custom alert and present it.